# Setting up Application Load Balancer for Private Subnet EC2 instances running tomcat

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, private-subnet

I have setup a VPC with two public subnets and two private subnets. The two private subnets have two EC2 instates and each has tomcat server running on port 8080.

I have set up a load balancer (terraform) as following but the health check is always failing. Can someone help me with what's wrong here.

**Security Groups:**

```
# Create Security Group for the Application Load Balancer
# terraform aws create security group
resource "aws_security_group" "alb-security-group" {
  name        = "ALB Security Group"
  description = "Enable HTTP/HTTPS access on Port 80/443"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.OrchVPC.id

  ingress {
    description = "HTTP Access"
    from_port   = 80
    to_port     = 80
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  ingress {
    description = "HTTPS Access"
    from_port   = 443
    to_port     = 443
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "ALB Security Group"
  }
}

# Create Security Group for the Bastion Host aka Jump Box
# terraform aws create security group
resource "aws_security_group" "ssh-security-group" {
  name        = "SSH Security Group"
  description = "Enable SSH access on Port 22"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.OrchVPC.id

  ingress {
    description = "SSH Access"
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "SSH Security Group"
  }
}

# Create Security Group for the Web Server
# terraform aws create security group
resource "aws_security_group" "webserver-security-group" {
  name        = "Web Server Security Group"
  description = "Enable HTTP/HTTPS access on Port 80/443 via ALB and SSH access on Port 22 via SSH SG"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.OrchVPC.id

  ingress {
    description     = "HTTP Access"
    from_port       = 80
    to_port         = 80
    protocol        = "tcp"
    security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.alb-security-group.id}"]
  }

  ingress {
    description     = "HTTPS Access"
    from_port       = 443
    to_port         = 443
    protocol        = "tcp"
    security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.alb-security-group.id}"]
  }

  ingress {
    description     = "HTTP/HTTPS Access"
    from_port       = 8080
    to_port         = 8080
    protocol        = "tcp"
    security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.alb-security-group.id}"]
  }

  ingress {
    description     = "SSH Access"
    from_port       = 22
    to_port         = 22
    protocol        = "tcp"
    security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.ssh-security-group.id}"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "Web Server Security Group"
  }
}
```

**Load Balancer:**

```
# Target group for application load balancer
resource "aws_lb_target_group" "targetgroup" {
  health_check {
    interval            = 5
    path                = "/"
    protocol            = "HTTP"
    timeout             = 2
    healthy_threshold   = 2
    unhealthy_threshold = 2
  }

  stickiness {
    type    = "lb_cookie"
    enabled = true
  }

  name        = "targetgroup"
  port        = 8080
  protocol    = "HTTP"
  target_type = "instance"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.OrchVPC.id
}

# Load Balancer Target Group attachment for first instance
resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "myec2vm1tg1" {
  target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.targetgroup.arn
  target_id        = aws_instance.myec2vm1.id
  port             = 8080
}

# Load Balancer Target Group attachment for second instance
resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "myec2vm2tg1" {
  target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.targetgroup.arn
  target_id        = aws_instance.myec2vm2.id
  port             = 8080
}


# Applicaiton Load Balancer
resource "aws_lb" "alb" {
  name               = "alb"
  internal           = false
  load_balancer_type = "application"
  security_groups    = [aws_security_group.alb-security-group.id]
  subnets            = [aws_subnet.PublicSubnet1.id, aws_subnet.PublicSubnet2.id]

  tags = {
    Name = "alb"
  }

  timeouts {
    create = "30m"
    delete = "30m"
  }
}

# Load Balancer Listener
resource "aws_lb_listener" "alblistener" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.alb.arn
  port              = "80"
  protocol          = "HTTP"

  default_action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.targetgroup.arn
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check in console -> security group of those instances to ensure, it has given inbound rule so that load balancer can do the HTTP request to your web server.

[security group inbound rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiIy4.png)